# Is there any deep reason that special trig angles are a sequence of roots of integers?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

We all are familiar with certain special values of sin and cos, e.g. $\sin(30^\circ)=0.5$, $\sin(45^\circ)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ etc. In high school I found these values difficult to remember until I noticed they could be reformulated as this pattern:

$$\sin(0^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{0}}{2}$$

$$\sin(30^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}$$

$$\sin(45^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

$$\sin(60^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

$$\sin(90^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{4}}{2}$$

This has been bugging me for years ever since. I know to expect there to be some deep cause of patterns when I see them, but I have no idea what causes these common special angle values to be half-roots-of-integers, or whether this pattern is just a special case of a more general notion of special trig angles.

What's the explanation? Why should this be so?

Comment: Lol...and you can derive more "special angles" along these lines by the way.

Comment: How? arcsin((sqrt(5)/2) is transcendental, for example.

Comment: :-) I'll try to find it.

Comment: To derive $\sin(45°)$, just consider a triangle with angles $90°$ and twice $45°$. It is easy to see that the lengths of the sides are $x,x,\sqrt{2}\cdot x$. Now, basic properties of triangles with an angle of $90°$ are enough to calculate $\sin(45°)$.

Comment: Yes, I can see the arguments for specific angles, I'm looking for an argument for the pattern. Or is my way of writing it an arbitrary numerical fluke with no intrinsic meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The intervals between the angles are not uniform.  Somehow it's mathematical coincidence:

Since $\sin (90^{\circ}-\theta)=\sqrt{1-\sin^{2} \theta}$,

$$\sin 0^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{0}}{2} \iff \sin 90^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{4}}{2}$$

$$\sin 30^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2} \iff \sin 60^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

We might invent a mnemonic in this way:

$$\sin 35.26^{\circ}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\sin 54.74^{\circ}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$$

These angles relate to tetrahedron and are special angles in another way.

Comparing the $\color{green}{\textbf{fitting curve}}$ with $\color{red}{\boldsymbol{\sin \dfrac{\pi x}{12}}}$ below:

[image]

Comment: What is the fitting line and what is it's motivation or relevance?

Comment: Just interpolating the special angles mentioned and comparing with the true sine curve.  When I was a student, I used to sketch a sine curve with every $30^{\circ}$-interval as benchmarks - a very good fit.

Answer (score 1):

Unsatisfying explanation: $\sin: [0,\pi/2]\to [0,1]$ is a monotonically increasing homeomorphism, so you'll always be able to find values which solve $\sin(a)=b$ for $b\in[0,1]$ and if you pick $b$ to be a sequence like $\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n}$ where $k$ runs from $0$ to $n^2$, you'll see the same sort of mirrored progression in the angles, as $\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(\pi/2-x)=1$.

To me, the real gem here is that rational multiples of $\pi$ give algebraic numbers under $\sin$ and $\cos$ (and therefore under $\tan,\sec,\csc,\cot$ where appropriately defined). Here's why:

Suppose $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$. We can write it as a rational multiple of $2\pi$: $\theta=\frac{2p\pi}{q}$. By De Moivre's formula, we have that $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^q=\cos(q\theta)+i\sin(q\theta)=1$, so $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ is algebraic, and so each of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ are as well (if $a+bi$ is algebraic, then $a-bi$ is also algebraic, as algebraicness is preserved under field automorphisms, and so $(a+bi)+(a-bi)=2a$ is algebraic as well, and therefore since algebraic numbers form a field, we have that $a=\frac{2a}{2}$ and $b=\frac{a+bi-a}{i}$ are algebraic).

Comment: I actually find that more satisfying an explanation than the others :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a table.

$$\begin{array}{ccccc|l}\frac{\sqrt 0}{2}&\frac{\sqrt 1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}&\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}&\frac{\sqrt 4}{2}&\text{sin}\\\hline0&30&45&60&90&\text{angle (deg)}
\\0&2&3&4&6&\text{multiple of 15}\\
1&0&1&0&1&\text{divisible by 45?}\\
1&1&0&1&1&\text{divisible by 30?}\\\end{array}$$

By periodicity this is a combination of the cyclic groups $\frac{360}{45} = 8$ and $\frac{360}{30} = 12$ considering rotation as the generator. This means we will stay in the set $\pm\left\{\frac{\sqrt 0}{2},\frac{\sqrt 1}{2},\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},\frac{\sqrt 3}{2},\frac{\sqrt 4}{2}\right\}$ if starting from 0, subset $\pm\left\{\frac{\sqrt 0}{2},\frac{\sqrt 1}{2},\frac{\sqrt 3}{2},\frac{\sqrt 4}{2}\right\}$ if 30 degrees and $\pm\left\{\frac{\sqrt 0}{2},\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},\frac{\sqrt 4}{2}\right\}$ if 45 degrees. Number theoretic every integer times 15 deg which is a multiple of 2 **or** 3. And with a rotation of 15 degrees we can get a rather peculiar overlap.